# What is the best practice for saving user data in Firestore/Firebase?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Specifically, should/can one one think of 'Collections' as table names and 'Documents' as unique keys ?

Should you use auto generated key, Auth uid or user email as documents names ?

What are the pros and cons of each if any ?

-Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, collections very closely resemble table names, as they would represent entities in object-oriented perspective. The documents are unique since each must have a unique id, the ids are the unique keys that identify each instance of an entity. No document can share a firebase id with another of the same collection.

Auth id keys seem to be the best idea for user firebase id's as it will allow you to sync between the firebase Auth, and Firestore/Firebase database, right out of the box. This is what I usually prefer. I would use autogenerated id's for other objects which have not been integrated into any other Firebase service. Having a consistent user id for both Firebase Auth,Firestore masks thing quite easy, since I only need to know one id, to access both services from the client end.